# Why .TFWX file has been created even after second and third-order transformation after updating georeferencing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have a query and I am curious to know why. TFWX file has been created even after second and third-order transformation after updating georeferencing? Is it an expected behavior or do we have any supporting documents that explain this?

[image]

As per my knowledge, .tfwx is the extension for a TIFF image with this approximate affine transformation. This is to indicate that this is not a standard world document and that it is simply a fair approximation. An affine or first-order transformation from pixel space to map space is stored in a world file. Update Georeference generates a world file when an image is georeferenced and the transformation may be written in the form of a world file.

So far, I've looked through all of ESRI's websites, documentation, and articles, but no relevant material has been found.

However, here's what I did to put that to the test: I tried georeferencing in ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro with an in-house tiff file and tested with affine transformation as well as directly for 2nd and 3rd order transformations; however, in both scenarios, a.tfwx file was generated, and I noticed that when I georeferenced a tiff file and clicked on update georeferencing after Affine, a.tfwx file was created, and after that, I jumped on second-order transformation and noticed that the same .tfwx file was updated.